# Dynamically sort posts by tags into a Wordpress loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I got a a custom loop into my Wordpress custom blog page, and Im displaying all my posts into it, like that :

```
<section class="container blog-article-actu">
            <div class="row">

    <?php
    $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=-1');

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
    $catObj = get_the_category();

        ?>

        <article class="blog-article-actu-article" style="background:url('<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' ); ?><?php echo $url ?>');">
            <div class="blog-article-actu-article-top">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <div class="details-blog-article-actu">
                    <div class="blog-article-actu-date">
                        <span class="day"><?php the_time( 'd' ) ?></span><br>
                        <span class="month"><?php the_time( 'F' ) ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><p>

                        <?php
                            if (($catObj[0]->name == 'Actualités et évènements') OR ($catObj[1]->name == 'Actualités et évènements')) {
                              echo "<img src=\"XXX/actu-icon.png\" alt=\"Actualités et évènements\">";
                            } elseif (($catObj[0]->name == 'Témoignages') OR ($catObj[1]->name == 'Témoignages')) {
                              echo "<img src=\"XXX/chat-icon.png\" alt=\"Témoignages\">";
                            } elseif (($catObj[0]->name == 'Vidéos') OR ($catObj[1]->name == 'Vidéos')) {
                              echo "<img src=\"XXX/video-icon.png\" alt=\"Vidéos\">";
                            } else {
                              echo "";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </p></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="blog-article-actu-article-bottom-wrap">
                <span class="blog-article-actu-article-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt();?></span>
                <span class="blog-article-actu-article-bottom"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">En savoir <span>+</span></a></span>
                <div class="social-blog-article-actu">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink() ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

    <?php  // End of the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>

            </div>
    </section>
```

Then I was asked to build something to sort them, by tags, dynamically, with a tag system like this one : https://codepen.io/Chaaampy/pen/gWOrvp

But Im a bit lost about that ... I thought about get the tags for each posts in my loop, and then add them as a CSS class, like that maybe I could show or hide some articles in JS ... Meh, I don't know, has someone got any ideas for me ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, found a solution by building something like that : https://codepen.io/Chaaampy/pen/gWOrvp

```
$(function filter() {
    var selectedClass = "";
    $(".link").click(function(){ 
    selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
$(".wrap").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
    $(".wrap section").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale_anm');
setTimeout(function() {
  $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale_anm');
  $(".wrap").fadeTo(300, 1);
}, 300);
});
```

});

Note that I get the tags into Wordpress with get_the_tags, and then I add them as a class to the elements I want to show / hide